# Error (10219): Verilog HDL Continuous Assignment error at Mux.v(19): object "muxout" on left-hand side of assignment must have a net type

Tags: verilog, quartus

I want to make Frequency Divider with Counter and MUX.

I make 3 module for project

// 4-bit Counter

```
module Counter (input clk, input reset, output reg[3:0] out);

   always@(posedge clk or posedge reset)
   begin
      if(reset)
         out = 4'b0000; 
      else
      begin
         if(clk)
            if(out < 4'b1111)
            out = out + 4'b0001;
            else
            out = 4'b0000;
      end
   end


endmodule
```

---

//module 4by1 Mux

```
module Mux (input [3:0] muxin , input [1:0] sel, output reg muxout);


   function _4by1mux;

      input [3:0] muxin;
      input [1:0] sel;

      case (sel)
         2'b00 : _4by1mux = muxin[0];
         2'b01 : _4by1mux = muxin[1];
         2'b10 : _4by1mux = muxin[2];
         2'b11 : _4by1mux = muxin[3];
      endcase
   endfunction

   assign muxout = _4by1mux(muxin, sel);


endmodule
```

---

//module freqDivider

```
 module freqDivider(input clk, input reset, input [1:0] sel, output reg muxout);

   wire [3:0]counterbus;

   Counter ct1 (clk, reset, counterbus);
   Mux mux1 (counterbus, sel, muxout);

endmodule
```

module freqDivider is top, and I call module Counter and Mux

but module Mux has problem with

```
Error (10219): Verilog HDL Continuous Assignment error at Mux.v(19):
object "muxout" on left-hand side of assignment must have a net type
```

this error

ps. input sel will be changed by time

Comment: please format you code using Cntrl + K. Also please explain your problem in detail and also where you need the help for resolution of your issue

Comment: sorry this is my first time  coding
and I think output 'muxout' can't be assigned.... but why?

Comment: FYI: not related to your problem statement, but you should remove the line `if(clk)`. Simulations will run fine but most synthesizers will consider all signals uses in a procedural blocks (aka `always @(posedge/negedge ...)`) sensitivity list and used in the body as asynchronous inputs. Without the line `if(clk)` you `Counter` module will simulate the same and will synthesize correctly

Comment: Oh, I understand. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is a result of the `muxout` output having type `reg` instead of type `wire`. In verilog, lines can have two overarching types, either nets (like `wire` type) or variables (like `reg` types). To assign values/logic to net types, you need to use `assign` statements and not `always` blocks. To assign values/logic to variable types, you can only use `always` blocks and not `assign` statements. So, you can either make your `assign` in the `Mux` module an `always` block or, for an easier solution, don't make the `muxout` output a `reg`, just leave out the `reg` keyword and it will be a `wire`.

Comment: thanks, I change my code and it works!
but still confuse about net type...
anyway thanks a lot!!

Comment: @KorHotGuy It is a little strange and I wrote this answer on a train on my phone so I didnt go all out on the explanation. However, newer version of Verilog (or, more correctly, SystemVerilog) have tried to remove this problem by making everything youd normal use of type `logic`

Answer (score 0):

Error is that you have declared `mux_out` as reg type, instead of  wire type. Default type of any port is wire. You are doing continuous assignment on that net through `assign` keyword. And on `reg` type nets, assignment can only be done inside procedural block (initial, always).

Change to `mux_out` from `output reg` to `output` only.